# Включить рандомную песню с помощью random.choice и pyautogui

Tags: случайные-числа, pyautogui

Я хочу выбрать наугад любую песню, которую можно включить с помощью библиотеки puautogui. У меня есть следующий код:

```
import pyautogui as p
import os
import sleep
os.system(r'start " " "E:\audio_for_automatization"')
sleep(1)
list_of_audio = ["p.locateOnScreen(r'E:\images_for_automatization\happy_fun.png', confidence=.9)",
"p.locateOnScreen(r'E:\images_for_automatization\in_my_zone.png', confidence=.9)",
"p.locateOnScreen(r'E:\images_for_automatization\harrison_amer.png', confidence=.9)"]

random_audio = (random.choice(list_of_audio))

sleep(1)
p.moveTo(random_audio)
p.douclick()
```

Но на выходе получаем ошибку, которая говорит о том, что такого файла нет. Но если просто использовать любую из картинок напрямую без random.choice, допустим:

```
p.moveTo(p.locateOnScreen(r'E:\images_for_automatization\harrison_amer.png', confidence=.9)
```

то без проблем находит эту песню.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\testing_file.py", line 39, in p.moveTo(random_audio) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_init_.py", line 598, in wrapper returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_init_.py", line 1280, in moveTo x, y = normalizeXYArgs(x, y) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_init.py", line 661, in normalizeXYArgs location = locateOnScreen(firstArg) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_init.py", line 175, in wrapper return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyautogui_init_.py", line 213, in locateOnScreen return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_init_.py", line 373, in locateOnScreen retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_init_.py", line 353, in locate points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs)) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_init_.py", line 207, in _locateAll_opencv needleImage = load_cv2(needleImage, grayscale) File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze_init.py", line 170, in _load_cv2 raise IOError("Failed to read %s because file is missing, " OSError: Failed to read p.locateOnScreen(r'E:\images_for_automatization\in_my_zone.png', confidence=.9) **because file is missing, has improper permissions, or is an unsupported or invalid format**

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что файлов с именем начинающимся на `p.locateOnScreen(` у вас и в самом деле нет...

Comment: забыл написать, что импортировал pyautogui as p

Comment: Это никак не изменит факта несуществования файлов начинающихся на `p.locateOnScreen(`